# Treat NULL the same as T-SQL in SEDE interactive sort on numeric columns

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

In SEDE, SQL Server always places `null` values first in ascending order, and last in descending order.

However, the interactive column sort in SEDE (click column headers) always treats `null` values as 0 in numeric columns.

For example, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/677338):

```
create table #example (value int)
insert into #example values (-1)
insert into #example values (-2)
insert into #example values (-3)
insert into #example values (1)
insert into #example values (2)
insert into #example values (3)
insert into #example values (null)
insert into #example values (null)

select * from #example order by value asc
```

Yields the SQL server sort order initially:

[image]

But when the column is clicked once (interactive ascending) it changes to:

[image]

And a second click (interactive descending) yields:

[image]

And it is never possible to return to the original sort order without re-running the query.

I'd like this behavior to be changed so that the interactive sort order matches the normal sort order (nulls first with ascending, last with descending) rather than being treated as zero.

I'm tagging this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) rather than [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as I have a feeling this is currently by design.